# Rig transforms using rigify and follow path constraint

Tags: bones, transforms, constraints, rigify

[image]

I've been learning blender for a couple months now and I have created a character that I am attempting to animate. The rig for my character was created using rigify which worked wonderfully initially.

I have since been animating my character however, I found that at one point the rig no longer responded in pose mode when trying to rotate transform the bones.  I have found that the transform menu and the object properties is responsive to rotations however, I'd like to be able to transform the bones more naturally in pose mode.  I would note that I'm also trying to incorporate a follow path constraint as well.. not sure if this may be playing a role.  I can re-rig my character and start fresh for future animations, but i would like to avoid having to go that route if possible..

In the attached image, the purple section is where i'm unable to rotate transform bones, but i'm able to do so in the orange sections.

Is there something I need to tweak or adjust to enable me to be able to rotate my bones in pose mode again?

Thanks!

Comment: Odds are good that you've accidentally enabled some "Affect only" option.  Look in sidebar/tool/affect only, make sure nothing is checked.

Comment: What Nathan said, or you're trying to use the FK bones when you're in IK... The image you posted is not very helpful, to be honest. I literally have no idea what I am looking at...